# Clojure — partial in `->` macro

Tags: clojure

I've just started using Clojure, and I was wondering why the following doesn't work as expected:

```
(-> 5
    -
    (partial + 5))
```

I would expect the result of this expression to be 0 (-5 + 5), but instead the whole thing seems to be a partial.

```
(macroexpand `(-> 5 - (partial + 5))
  #_=> )
(clojure.core/partial (clojure.core/-> 5 clojure.core/-) clojure.core/+ 5)
```

Why is this, and how can I do what I wanted to?

Comment: May be you don't need partial at this case? `(-> 5 - (+ 5))`

Answer (score 10, accepted):

needs an extra set of parens:

```
user> (-> 5 - ((partial + 5)))                                                                                                                                            
0
```

the `->` macro inserts the result of the previous expression as the second argument in the list so in your example it would exand to `(partial (- 5) + 5)` with the extra () it gets inserted after the partial function `((partial + 5) (- 5))`

Comment: Aha, that makes perfect sense. Thanks.